# Does Interstitial Ad require uses-permission in the manifest?

Tags: android, google-play-services

There is an official example on how to use [Interstitial Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) that does not have an additional `uses-permission` elements in the manifest.

But there is [another example](https://github.com/yevgeniy-logachev/QtAdMob) that has the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

see the [picture](https://github.com/yevgeniy-logachev/QtAdMob/blob/master/AndroidManifest.png) on github.

1) Should I include these `uses-permission` elements to my app if I it uses Interstitial Ads?

2) Is user prompted to allow these permissions when the app starts?

**EDIT1:**

If I build the app with Google Play Services and Interstitial Ads but does not include additional permissions to the manifest I get the following warnings when I upload the app to the store:

[image]

Is this a normal behavior or something is wrong with the app.

Comment: No, you don’t need to all these permissions, the user won’t be prompted for these permissions but only for the write access permission, you don’t need it for the adds though

Comment: @JaswantSingh Even if I do not add the permissions to the manifest, they are added implicitly somehow if I build the app with Interstitial Ads, see EDIT1.